# GCP gcloud script to compare all project roles with a list of roles in a file

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Looking for a script to obtain all the roles for all the projects in the Org and then compare them to a list of roles in a compare.txt file and if the roles match then get the role and the projectID for where it matches.

the roles in the compare.txt file are listed as follows.

```html
roles/abc
roles/xyz
roles/123
roles/example.admin
roles/billing.xyz
```

again there are 2 parts to this task.

1. get the roles for all the projects in the org (maybe something like " `for project in $(gcloud project list) do gcloud projects get-iam-policy $project | grep role done > list.txt`

> Blockquote
> 2) compare all the roles from step 1 to the roles in compare.txt and whenever they match get the project ID and role of where they match.

Comment: Can you show what you have you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Consider inverting the problem.

Define a list of roles of interest:

```sh
WANTS=("roles/editor" "roles/datastore.user")
```

Then extract (an already unique) set of roles from a Project's bindings:

```sh
ROLES=$(\
  gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT} \
  --flatten="bindings" \
  --format="value(bindings.role)")
```

Then enumerate all Projects and check for each desired role:

```sh
WANTS=("roles/editor" "roles/datastore.user")

PROJECTS=$(\
  gcloud projects list \
  --format="value(projectId)")

for PROJECT in ${PROJECTS}
do
  ROLES=$(\
    gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT} \
    --flatten="bindings" \
    --format="value(bindings.role)")
  for ROLE in ${ROLES}
  do
    if [[ "${WANTS[@]}" =~ "${ROLE}" ]]
    then
      echo "Project: ${PROJECT} contains ${ROLE}"
    fi
  done
done
```